# Sublime Text 3: How to change the notation from ``->cls`` to some macro?

Tags: regex, sublimetext

I am trying to edit a big C++ file and there are about 1000 cases where there is something like

```
somepointers->cls
```

Due to some reasons I want to change all of them to the form

```
GETCLASS(somepointer)
```

where `GETCLASS` is a pre-defined macro. I tried to use the regular expression search and replace built in sublime text 3 but I cannot get it working, can you give me some advice?

Comment: @Kasra what do you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the find-replace dialog `ctrl+H` then search for `([\w-]+)->cls` and replace with `GETCLASS($1)`

[image]

Comment: And if the pointer doesn't have the same name search for ([\w_\-]+)->cls

Comment: @Astyan Oh, true, I don't know what I was thinking... Fixed <3

Comment: @Astyan BTW, `_` is already included in `\w`, and no need to escape `-` if it's at the begining or the end of a character class